# Why can't I pass this function to onMouseEnter in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I think the answer is related to the context of 'this'. I am getting an error of 'cannot read props of undefined' when trying to render the createTrack by passing it the handleEnter() function. I can however, pass it a regular function without 'this' such as song.play();

Can someone give a better explanation?

```
 handleEnter(){
    this.song.play();
        //    this.props.mouseEnter();
 }
createTrack(track){
    var song = new Audio([track.preview_url]);


    return   ( 
                <div className="image" key={track.id}>
                    <img className="img-circle" src={track.album.images[0].url} onMouseEnter={this.handleEnter.bind(this)} onMouseLeave={()=>song.pause()}/>
                    <p className="showMe"><span>{track.name}</span></p>
                    <p className="showMeArtist"><span>{track.artists[0].name}</span></p>

                </div>
                );
}
getTracks(){
if(this.props.tracks){
    console.log(this.props.tracks);
 return <div>{this.props.tracks.map(this.createTrack)}</div>
    }
}
 render(){
    return(
                    <div>{this.getTracks()}</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the issue. add bind to the function parameter of map. Like this:

```
return <div>{this.props.tracks.map(this.createTrack, this)}</div>
```

Edit:
I've changed my answer a bit. When map calls createTrack this is undefined unless you give it a thisArg param. Without thisArg map doesn't have the scope of which the function was written in. Here is the explanation from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) -

> If a thisArg parameter is provided to map, it will be passed to
>   callback when invoked, for use as its this value. Otherwise, the value
>   undefined will be passed for use as its this value. The this value
>   ultimately observable by callback is determined according to the usual
>   rules for determining the this seen by a function.

Comment: You might want to elaborate a bit why this is the issue.

Comment: let me know if this made sense.

Comment: is this the es6 equivalent? if I use an arrow function? {this.props.tracks.map(track => this.createTrack(track))}

Comment: it will work, but there is no need for the arrow function when you have thisArg and can provide it easily.

Answer (score 0):

song is local to *createTrack()*. I suggest you put song in the state and access it via this.state.song.

Comment: You can have a state with an array of songs and one active song(playing)

Comment: I can't set the state in the map function or else the component goes into an infinite rerendering loop

Comment: this.props.tracks is an array, right? then this.state.tracks = this.props.tracks